# Paste special method of range class failed vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MakeTables()
    Dim wbTarget As Object

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\GenerateTablesFormulas.xlsx")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\Desmond\VBAProject\USDReport.xlsx")

    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    .Copy

    ' Create the new sheet and name it at the end

        With wbTarget.Sheets("HK").Range("D82:X97")
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Can someone tell me what mistake I made here. It gives me the error that range class failed. Thank you

Comment: You can't have `With wbTarget.Sheets("HK")` inside a `With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` that is another `Worksheet` in another `Workbook` object. You should close the first `With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange` with `End With` and only then start the second one of `With wbTarget.Sheets("HK").Range("D82:X97")`

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I separated it out already but still got the same error

Comment: at what line are you getting your error?

Comment: Getting the error at .PasteSpecial xlValues

Comment: are the dimensions of Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange are identical to the dimension of Sheets("HK").Range("D82:X97")? if no, then you will get this error.

Comment: No I copied from A1:S16 and pasted into D82:X97. Same size dimensions but different starting point. How can I fix this?

Comment: @ShaiRado You can have an unrelated `With` block within another without problem. There's not a lot of point to the first `With` block here though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the *copied* range size, then:

```
With wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    .Copy

    ' Create the new sheet and name it at the end

    With wbTarget.Sheets("HK").Range("D82") '.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) '<--| you can omit the 'Resize' part but it can be useful to make it clear (code can be read in years to come) you want to stick to copied range size
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| empty clipboard
```

otherwise if you want to `force` the copied range size to the *to-be-pasted* one, then:

```
' Create the new sheet and name it at the end

With wbTarget.Sheets("HK").Range("D82:X97") '<--| reference range you want to paste values to and keep sizes of
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Copy '<--| copy the source sheet range with same sizes as referenced range

    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False '<--| empty clipboard
```

Comment: @Desmond; did you try any of thise solutions?